# Does notifydatasetchanged call onCreateViewHolder when using RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-adapter, android-recyclerview, notifydatasetchanged

I want to use a toggle to toggle between two different views but using the same `RecyclerView`. Basically, once you toggle, I want the `RecyclerView` adapter to recall `onCreateViewHolder()` but this time it will use a different layout item file.

Does `notifydatasetchanged()` cause the adapter to rebuild itself? Or is there another way?

Comment: one way to find out is simply put `Log`s inside `onCreateViewHolder` and check if they are being called on `notifydatasetchanged()`... `:P` is that so hard?

Comment: Fair enough, but i actually want to know what the process is. I tried looking it up. Also that wasn't my only question. Sorry I asked

Comment: No worries if you have another question then either edit this question or delete this question and post a new question `:)`. you might wanna read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: No I am saying in my above post I asked what is another way of doing this. I had a feeling that the notifydatasetchanged() wouldn't do what I wanted.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I needed to have two types on `View`s on my `RecyclerView` `Adapter` as well, one for 'regular' mode and one for multi-select mode.

So, you can override `getItemViewType` to force the Adapter to call your `onCreateViewHolder` for all views.

Add this to the `Adapter` code:

```
public void setActionMode(ActionMode actionMode) {
    this.actionMode = actionMode;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return (actionMode == null ? 0 : 1);
}
```

Add this to the `ViewHolder`:

```
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view;
    if (viewType == 0) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_1, parent, false);
    } else {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_2, parent, false);
    }
    ...
}
```

Since you return a different `ViewType` when in an `ActionMode`, the Adapter is forced to throw away all created views, and recreate everything again.

Comment: Omg this works. Just by overriding getItemViewType, even though we can technically the actionMode directly in onCreateViewHolder, forces the adapter to call onCreateViewHolder like you said. Thanks!

Comment: i cant belive this answers save my day :D

Answer (score 16):

`notifyDataSetChanged()` calls `onBindViewHolder()` in case of `RecyclerView`

Comment: It never calls it for me.

Answer (score 4):

**THE SIMPLEST SOLUTION**

If you want to refresh RecyclerView items and `onCreateView()` be called too, say for **Grid** and  **List** `LayoutManager`s.

```
  void refreshRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView){
            Adapter adapterRef=recyclerView.getAdapter();
            recyclerView.setAdapter(null);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterRef);
        }
```

it will completely refresh the RecyclerView

```
//example usage
refreshRecyclerView(yourRecyclerView);
```

Comment: By far the simplest solution.  I have a Recycler view that adds/deletes various types of items with different view holders in different locations.  Refreshing the adapter as this solution states works perfectly.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

To remove and update layout in `RecyclerView`, you can call

```
mRecyclerView.removeView(view);
```

OR

```
mRecyclerView.removeViewAt(position);
```

after removing object in your dataset

Answer (score 0):

I spent more than 6 hours on this issue without any success.
Finally!!!
I set a global variable in the adapter and had to set it up every time i toggled the view from list to grid (in my case). the funny thing this approauch was there but I forgot to do it as static!! So my solution could be related to yours , just try it and hope it works out.

```
public static int mCurrentViewType;
```

then override the getItemType()

```
  @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {

       return mCurrentViewType;


    }
```

my toggleItemViewType method:

```
public void toggleItemViewType () {
        if (mCurrentViewType == LIST_ITEM){
            mCurrentViewType = GRID_ITEM;
        } else {
            mCurrentViewType = LIST_ITEM;
        }
    }
```

I am accessing the variable from different classes, which is not right, but for now and for the sake of the onCreateViewHolder issue, it worked!
if you have a better solution then good luck and share it with us.
don't forget to make the global variable as "static" :)

Answer (score -1):

Yes it will assume that its current data set is invalid and would need to relayout and rebind all layouts.

Comment: No, it seems it only calls the onBindViewHolder when the notifydatasetchanged() is called. Thanks for trying to help though.

Comment: No problem thanks well there are always 20 ways to achieve a result you want, its just choosing which one :)

Comment: Haha, I would like just one please :P

Comment: maybe call setAdapter rather than notifyDataSetChanged

Comment: haha thanks! Tyring that now.. Also tried calling invalidate() but that did nothing